# How to add a single file from a directory to git ignore?

Tags: git, gitignore

Let say, i have a asp.net mvc project(Git Enabled from CMD hosted in bitbucket) in visual studio 2015 service pack 1.
my project folder looks like this following:

```
MyProject
|
|--DAL--DataManager
|.gitignore
|MyProject.sln
|Other files
|--Other folders
```

now i want to untrack update on a File in DAL/DataManager/ConnectionSettings.cs

my .gitignore file is like below
http://pastebin.com/QRdSTdEK

how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute `git ls-files` in the terminal,it will list all files being tracked. In your case, you need to first tell git to stop tracking your file.

```
 git rm --cached DAL/DataManager/ConnectionSettings.cs
```

If you check for status, you can see the file is now untracked. Add the following line in .gitignore.

```
DAL*/DataManager/ConnectionSettings.cs
```

Now do a commit and say "removed ConnectionSettings.cs"